# Rendering Modal Popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

My goal is to launch a modal pop-up during the event a button is clicked. I've been having issues making the Axios API call to the function that contains the modal. The process of the API call has been listed below:

**First:** This is the button where the Axios post request is made (addToCart) (works fine)

```
<button className="button is-primary" onClick={addToCart}>
   ADD TO CART
</button>
```

**Second:** This is the Axios post request that makes a call to the modal pop-up (Example()) (works fine)

```
const addToCart = () => {
    Axios.post(
       //standard backend API call is made here
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("post called")
        Example(); //I want to launch my modal when this state is reached
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      });
```

**Third:** This is the modal that I'd like to popup but have been having issues rendering the function (Issue)

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

```html
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

I receive the following **error**:

```
  Line 38:3:  'render' is not defined  no-undef
```

How can I properly render my modal pop-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a `show` state in your `Example` component, receive this data in a prop. In addition, you'll also want to pass some callbacks to the component to be able to react to certain events (e.g. clicking "Close" or "Save Changes").

I'd do the following:

```
const Example = ({ show, onClose, onSave }) => (
  <Modal show={show} onHide={onClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={onSave}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
)
```

This way you could always render the `Example` component in some parent component and show it conditionally, like so:

```
const SomeParentComponent = () => {
  const [showExample, setShowExample] = useState(false)

  const addToCart = () => {
    Axios.post("http://example.com/api/add-to-cart")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("post called")
        setShowExample(true)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button className="button is-primary" onClick={addToCart}>
        ADD TO CART
      </button>

      <Example
        show={showExample}
        onClose={() => setShowExample(false)}
        onSave={() => setShowExample(false)}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks after changing how I defined my states, my modal launched perfectly after a button click. Any idea why the modal is in plain HTML text instead of being formatted like in the React-Bootstrap link?

Comment: I'm glad to hear my solution worked! Regarding the new issue, I'm gonna have to look at some updated code. If you won't be able to solve it, please create a new question and I'll be glad to help again.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll add a screenshot as well which will clarify my problem further

Comment: Just added a separate question regarding importing the React-Boostrap formatting