# React-Bootstrap Modal Is only styling in plain HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

This is a continuation from my previous post [Rendering Modal Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654399/rendering-modal-popup)

After editing my code, I was able to launch my modal pop-up but had issues having it styled the same way as in the tutorial.

This is the desired styling that I pulled from a React-Boostrap tutorial

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

[image: This is the desired modal that is styled according to React-Boostrap]

After running the same code as in the tutorial, this was my output. It's styled in plain HTML.

[image: This modal is styled in plain HTML]

This is my import statement which I've used to import dependencies from the tutorial

```
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Updated code which successfully launched my modal pop-up

```
const Example = ({ show, onClose, onSave }) => (
  <Modal show={show} onHide={onClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={onSave}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
)

const addToCart = () => {
    Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_API + "/cart/",)
      .then((res) => {
        setShowExample(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
        }
      });
  };

<div className="field is-grouped">
    <div className="control">
    <button className="button is-primary" onClick={addToCart}>
        ADD TO CART
    </button>

    <Example //added
        show={showExample}
        onClose={() => setShowExample(false)}
        onSave={() => setShowExample(false)}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Missing CSS maybe? https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets

Comment: This was it! I should've definitely known to import the CSS file for bootstrap...you're a lifesaver.

Comment: Glad I could help!